# find the domain of root of a logarithmic function

Tags: logarithms

I'm a little confused about this question since output of a logarithmic function varies from $ -\infty $ to $\infty$ .I should find the domain of this function:  $ y=\sqrt{\log_x(10-x^2)} $ . How can I find the interval that makes $\log_x(10-x^2)$ greater than zero?

Comment: In order for $\log_x(10-x^2)$ to be positive, $10-x^2$ must be greater than $1$. Also remember, however, that $\log_x$ needs to make sense at all, which puts additional constraints on $x$.

Comment: @Henning Makholm what about $x=-1,$ $x=1$?

Comment: I believe those are among the values Henning had in mind when warning of additional constraints on $x$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Among others, yes.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you for your correction. I've removed my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall for $a>0, a\neq 1,b>0$:

$$\log_ab=\frac{\ln b}{\ln a}$$

Thus we have

$$f(x)=\log_x(10-x^2)=\frac{\ln(10-x^2)}{\ln x}$$

Then $f(x)\geq 0$ if and only if $10-x^2\geq 1,x>1$ or $0<10-x^2\leq 1,0<x<1$. Since the later case cannot happen, then we must have $10-x^2\geq 1$ and $x>1$, which gives $1<x\leq3$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would suggest to write your $\log$ in a fixed basis $$\log_x(10-x^2) = \frac{\ln(10-x^2)}{\ln(x)}.$$

This changes your question to $$\frac{\ln(10-x^2)}{\ln(x)} > 0$$
or equivalently: $$\ln(x)\ln(10-x^2) > 0.$$

Now, you have to find all roots of $10-x^2$ which gives you the intervals where $\ln(10-x^2) > 0$ and then you are almost finished.

Answer (score 0):

You first must have $x>1$ because $\log_x(a)=\dfrac{\log(a)}{\log(x)} \implies$ $\log(x)\neq 0$ so $x \neq 1$ which means that $x>1$. Furthermore, the reason it must be greater than $1$ and not simply "not equal to" is to have a positive function for the square root. Notice that one may argue that both $\log(a)$ and $\log(x)$ can be negative and still have a positive function. However, for this example, such cannot happen because for $0<x<1$ the function  $ \ \log(10-x^2)>0$.

Another added constraint is that $10-x^2\geq 1$ in  order to have a a positive square root. Solving for $x$, gives $x\leq 3$ or $x\geq-3$.

Hence, combining both we have the domain for $x$ as $1< x \leq 3$